# Spring Pageable Sort change name of property

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, dto, spring-restcontroller

Is there a way to map properties of Sort objects? Just a little example:

a Dto

```java
public class OrderDto {
  private long totalAmount;
  private long openAmount;
}
```

and an entity

```java
@Entity
public class Order {
  private long amount;
}
```

and a controller

```java
@RestController
public class OrderController {


  @GetMapping("/orders")
  public Page<OrderDto> findOrders(Pageable pageable) {
   // Do something 
  }
}
```

I would now call `/orders?sort=totalAmount,desc`

Is it possible to **map the sort property**, in this case the `totalAmount` from the Dto to only `amount` to use this for a generated JPA query in a charmant way?

Comment: Have you tried registering a `Converter<Order, OrderDto>` to perform the conversion automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly if I get your question right, but...

Do I understand you correct, that you want to map the request-parameter `sort` with the value `totalAmount,desc` to be available through the `Sort` object of the given `Pageable` object as `amount` (with order `desc`)?

Because of the names you mention in your post, I expect that you have Spring Data on the classpath.

IDKFS but maybe class `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer` could help you to customize the `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` the way, that you can map the request-parameter like you want to have.

If not, it should be possible to provide a @Bean of type `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that implements the behavior you want to have.

I'm not completely sure if the framework allows to override the specific part you need to be customized but it is IMO worth to have a look. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look to the `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same situation and none of the answers I found on the internet were clear enough about how this was done using Spring so to make the situation clearer I'm going to post the solution I came up with.

### When would something like this be necessary?

The situation described would **arise when using DTO's in an API to give the consumer a certain representation of the object. Now, when the consumer tries to query the API about that object using the properties it knows of the object it might result in 500 errors or misleading because the API might not recognize straightaway the object or the properties the consumer is sending**. You could get rid of the DTO and have this solved but nobody would want to lose that layer of abstraction.

In the example the API transforms the field `amount` to `totalAmount` but when queried about `totalAmount` (client shouldn't have to know about the transformation or the real name of the property) the API, through the services and repositories, is unable to find the property `totalAmount`.

### How can this be handled in Spring?

So, how would you go about this in a manner that is compliant with Spring Boot? Logic would say that if in the controller's layer you are transforming the object to its DTO's representation there should be a way of transforming the queries at the same surface level instead of passing the problem down to be handled by the service layer or the repository layer. And that's the way to go.

First thing would be to create a `SortArgumentResolver` that would be in charge of modifying the properties passed as sort parameters while retaining the rest of the sorting parameters (careful with complex scenarios where you might have conflicting properties on different requests).

```java
public class OrderSortArgumentResolver implements SortArgumentResolver {
    private final SortArgumentResolver delegate;

    public OrderSortArgumentResolver(SortArgumentResolver delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return delegate.supportsParameter(parameter);
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Sort resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        Sort originalSort = delegate.resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
        Sort modifiedSort = Sort.unsorted();

        if(!originalSort.isEmpty()) {
            // INFO: this will retain any other sort parameter aside from the one being modified
            for (Sort.Order order : originalSort) {
                if (order.getProperty().equals("totalAmount")) {
                    modifiedSort = modifiedSort.and(Sort.by(order.getDirection(), "amount"));
                } else {
                    modifiedSort = modifiedSort.and(Sort.by(order.getDirection(), order.getProperty()));
                }
            }
        }

        return modifiedSort;
    }
}
```

Once you have the argument resolver you need to add it to the application configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final SortArgumentResolver sortArgumentResolver;

    public WebConfig(SortArgumentResolver sortArgumentResolver) {
        this.sortArgumentResolver = sortArgumentResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolver(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        // INFO: this will handle paged requests
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(new OrderSortArgumentResolver(sortArgumentResolver));
        resolvers.add(pageableResolver);

        //INFO: this will handle any other requests
        resolvers.add(new OrderSortArgumentResolver(sortArgumentResolver));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anybody in the same situation.